# How do to resize flash dimensions via actionscript?

Tags: flash

If you include a flash file via:

```
<object width="550" height="400">
<param name="movie" value="somefilename.swf">
<embed src="somefilename.swf" width="550" height="400">
</embed>
</object>
```

Are you able to collapse or expand the dimensions to 100x100 or 1000x1000 for example via action-script without HTML, JavaScript or anything apart from the flash file itself?

Answer (score 4):

In short, no. You might be able to use ExternalInterface to fire javascript at the DOM (assuming SWF and webpage originate from same domain), but pure Actionscript? No.

http://blog.sebastian-martens.de/2010/06/resize-flash-application-container/

Comment: The other options are any method you'd normally use to resize elements in a web page. When flash content is embedded into HTML, the size of the container is controlled from outside of Flash, so it can only be changed from outside, or via a means of calling code outside (like ExternalInterface).